# Inverse of non-normal matrix with separated spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a matrix which has a single simple eigenvalue $\lambda_0\ne 0$ with $|\lambda_0|<\epsilon$ with all other eigenvalues satisfying $|\lambda|>2\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Denote the left- and right eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_0$ and the corresponding spectral projection by
$$Ar_0=\lambda r_0, \quad A^\ast l_0=\overline{\lambda}l_0, \quad P_0:=\frac{r_0 l_0^\ast}{l_0^\ast r_0}, \quad Q_0:=1-P_0.$$
**Question:** Is it true that
$$\lVert A^{-1}Q_0\rVert \le\frac{C}{\epsilon}$$
with some constant $C$ independent of the dimension? Here $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ denotes the spectral norm, i.e. the largest singular value.

If the matrix $A$ was normal, then this would be trivial.

Comment: What is $A_0$? At first I thought it was a typo, but it is still there after you've edited your question.

Comment: @user1551 This was a typo

Answer (score 2):

You only have a bound on the spectral radius of
$(Q_0 A_0)^{-1}$ (since you killed the smallest eigenvalue of $A_0$).
However a bound on the spectral radius is not equivalent to a bound on the norm. Take for example the operator that sends $e_1$ to $\lambda_1 e_1$
and $e_1 - \delta e_2$ to $\lambda_2 (e_1 - \delta e_2)$.
Then the vector $v = e_1 - e_1 + \delta e_2$ is send to $\lambda_1 e_1 - \lambda_2 e_1 + \lambda_2 \delta e_2$
and for $\delta \to 0$ we get
$$
\frac{\vert\vert A(v) \vert\vert}{\vert\vert v \vert\vert} = 
\frac{\vert\vert A(v) \vert\vert}{\delta} \to \infty.
$$
If now $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of the operator above,
then the operator $A_0 = A^{-1} \oplus (\lambda_0 \cdot \text{id}_1):
\mathbb{C}^3 = \mathbb{C} ² \oplus \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^3$
should be a counterexample

Comment: I guess that you meant the restriction of the operator $Q_0 A$ to the image of $Q_0$

Comment: What is $\lambda_1$? Is it the eigenvalue of $e_1$? But $e_1$ has eigenvalue 1?

Comment: Yes, sorry. changed it. But the point is that you can choose the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $ \lambda_2 $ freely. Because the angle between the eigenspaces is so small the operator norm becomes very big

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. Consider the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{\frac{\epsilon}{2}&0\\ 0&4\epsilon B}
$$
where $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose eigenvalues have moduli $\ge1$. Then $P_0=1\oplus 0_{n\times n}$ and $Q_0=0\oplus I_n$ in turn,
$$
A^{-1}Q_0=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&\frac{1}{4\epsilon}B^{-1}}
\text{ and }
\|A^{-1}Q_0\|=\frac{1}{4\epsilon}\|B^{-1}\|.
$$
So, the conjecture that $\|A^{-1}Q_0\|$ is bounded above essentially means that the singular values of $B$ are bounded away from zero when its eigenvalues are bounded away from zero. As pointed out in a comment to the other answer, this is false because a matrix can be nearly singular (so that its singular values are close to zero) when the angle between eigen*spaces* are small. The eigen*values* are pretty irrelevant here.

For example, if we take $B=B^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&c\\ 0&-1}$, we will have $\|A^{-1}Q_0\|=\|\frac{1}{4\epsilon}B^{-1}\|\to\infty$ when $c\to\infty$. Here the dimension of $B$ is fixed but $B$ isn't entrywise bounded.

For another example, consider
$$
B=\pmatrix{1&0&\cdots&0&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\ &&1&0&1\\ &&&1&1\\ &&&&-1}.
$$
Let $v=(1,1,\ldots,1,-1)^T$ and $u=(0,0,\ldots,0,1)^T$. Then $Bv=u$. Hence $\|B^{-1}\|\ge\|B^{-1}u\|=\|v\|=\sqrt{n}\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$. Here $B$ is entrywise bounded above in moduli but the dimension of $B$ is not fixed. This example is related to the previous one in that our $B$ here is unitarily similar to $I_{n-2}\oplus\pmatrix{1&\sqrt{n-1}\\ 0&-1}$.